# Pandas: Save multiple sheets into separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file with multiple sheets, and I'd like to save each of sheets into a separate dataframe using a loop.

```
countries = ['Thailand', 'China']
for country in countries:
    (country + '_data') = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = country)
```

However I am getting an error message:
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

I know the assignment is incorrect, but how to build a correct loop that will produce separate dataframes for each of the sheets?

Comment: That is not how you declare a variable in Python. And by `that`, I mean this: `(country + '_data')`

Comment: You are trying to assign a dataframe to a tuple, e.g. `('a' + 'b') = pd.DataFrame()`. Hence the error.  Try using a dictionary comprehension instead: `d = {country: pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=country) for country in countries}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better method would be

1. using the built-in `pd.ExcelFile` method
2. using a dictionary to hold your sheets in a separate data frames.

for example:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
print(xl.sheet_names)
['China','Japan','Pakistan'...]
```

then you can assign them to a dict

```
d = {} # your dict.
for sheet in xl.sheet_names:
    d[f'{sheet}']= pd.read_excel(xl,sheet_name=sheet)
```

then you can call your individual dfs

```
d['China']
```

Comment: Similar, to but `pd.read_excel('pathtofile.xlsx',sheet_name = None)` will read in each sheet to a different dataframe organized in dictionary of `{'sheet_name': dataframe}`

Comment: @jtweeder you should add it as an answer, less code but less flexibility with subsetting the sheet names beforehand. Probably more memory efficient too.

Comment: I would, but the question is a duplicate of one that has a very robust answer already and I don't want to recreate it for the sake of recreation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is the kind of thing you're looking for since you asked for a loop. Keep in mind that using a loop makes it harder to assign the df to a variable.

Also note that read_excel reads the first sheet as 0

```
import pandas as pd

num_sheets = 3
sheets = dict()

for i in range(num_sheets):
    sheets[i] = pd.read_excel('./test.xlsx', sheet_name = i)
```

Using a dictionary is the only easy way to include a loop on the title.

If you don't need a loop you could simply use the read_excel part specifying the sheet name or number.

```
import pandas as pd

thailand_data = pd.read_excel('./test.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Thailand')
```