# How can I import several Excel sheets into separate pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I've reviewed this post: [Pandas: Save multiple sheets into separate dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58563546/pandas-save-multiple-sheets-into-separate-dataframe), however it doesn't seem to address my problem.

So this creates a dictionary with sheet names as keys, and dataframes as values:

```
sheets = pd.read_excel('Data Series.xlsx',sheet_name=None)
```

`sheets["CPI"]` outputs a dataframe.

What I want to do is assign that to its own dataframe like:
`df_CPI = sheets["CPI"]`, however I have about 10 sheets to do so I'd rather run it as a loop if possible.
Something like

```
for sheet,dataframe in sheets.items():
   df_`sheet` = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create dynamically variables, you have to use `globals()` or `locals()` (which is strongly discouraged). The `dict` version is better.

```
sheets = pd.read_excel('Data Series.xlsx',sheet_name=None)
for sheet, dataframe in sheets.items():
   globals()[f'df_{sheet}'] = dataframe
```

Now you can use `df_CPI` as a variable.

Comment: Thanks for this. One follow up that I have, is would there be a "better" way to do this? The names of the df's don't need to correspond to the sheets exactly.